# Why do some JavaScript functions require a new variable to be created, but others do not?

Tags: javascript, sorting, in-place

Why some functions like `toLowerCase()` when used on a string need to be assigned a new variable, but other functions like `sort()`, `reverse()`, or `pop()` do not when used on an array?

For example, the code below is wrong:

```
var str = "Hello World";
str.toLowerCase();
```

but the code below is correct:

```
var arr = ["This","is","my","array"]
arr.sort();
```

I am reading that when using `toLowerCase()` on a string, I must have the code written like this:

```
str = str.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because strings are immutable in JavaScript, which means you cannot change them. Every time you try to modify a string, you are effectively creating a new string with the changes.

So when you do `str.toLowerCase();`, it's not modifying `str`, it is actually making a copy of it with the lowercase of the letters.

The array is different because it is a list of references to the array items. You can change each item separately from the other items `arr[5]=11`. You can also add or remove an item. The `sort()` and `reverse()` functions re-arrange the items in the array.

By the way, this concept is not unique to JavaScript. Many other modern languages also make strings immutable (perhaps all languages that have `String` as a built-in type).